# wanderlust: force expunge on all IMAP folders?

Tags: wanderlust, imap

I'm using wanderlust under emacs 25.x.

I know that wanderlust properly expunges messages on the IMAP server when I delete them.

However, I have other IMAP clients (for example, the one I use on my Android device) which don't seem to properly expunge deleted messages on the same IMAP server.

Is there a way I can add some functionality to wanderlust so that when I invoke `wl-folder-check-all` or some similar function, it will perform an expunge upon all messages in all folders that it checks?

To be clear, I'm talking about messages that are already marked as deleted, and which don't show up in the wanderlust summary buffer. But they contribute to the total message count, because the other email client(s) haven't properly expunged them after deletion. My goal is to get wanderlust to expunge all these deleted-but-not-yet-expunged messages, so that they don't contribute to the total message count.

I haven't been able to find the WL function(s) necessary for performing this expunge.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You would first need to debug to find out why those messages are being included in the count, but not being included in the summary.  Once you figure out how programmatically identify those messages using the Wanderlust elmo simi apel infrastructure, then you can go about figuring out how to modify and/or delete them in bulk.

Comment: Well, I know why they are showing up in the "all" count: it's because they are marked as `\Deleted` in IMAP, but they are not yet expunged. Yes, I am doing the exact work that you suggested. I was just hoping that someone might know some details about how to do this in elmo/simi. If so, I'll be grateful for anyone to share those details. But even if not, I'm sure I'll eventually figure this out on my own.